# jQuery manipulate object inside .each()

Tags: jquery, this, each

I'm trying to get online status and number of viewers for some live streams. I'm getting array of objects from my site by AJAX. Then I'm iterating through array and adding values to these object. The problem is, when I log contents of these objects in console, I find newly created keys, but when I try to log value of that key it says it's undefined.

```
$.each(livestreams, function () {
    if(this.provider === 'TwitchTV') {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json?channel=' + this.channel.toLowerCase(),
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: 'jsonp',
            success: $.proxy(function (stream) {
                this.live = true;
                this.count = stream[0].channel_count;
            }, this)
        });
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://api.own3d.tv/liveCheck.php?live_id=' + this.channel,
            dataType: 'xml',
            success: $.proxy(function (stream) {
                this.live = stream.find('isLive').text();
                this.count = stream.find('liveViewers').text();
            }, this)
        });
    }
    console.log(this);
    /* returns
            channel: "garenatw"
            count: 8237
            id: "3"
            live: true
            name: "garena"
            provider: "TwitchTV"
            username: "grifon"
            __proto__: Object 
            (of course, only for this specific object)
        */
    console.log(this.live); // returns undefined
});
```

Comment: Can you post a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/almirsarajcic/C4Jur/
Sorry, I tried to format it using HTML, but it didn't work the way I expected.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're login the values potentially before they are set. Since you're working with ajax request, you shouldn't think linearly.

Instead of login your values outside at the end of your function, you should log them at the end of your success functions:

```
$.each(livestreams, function () {
    if(this.provider === 'TwitchTV') {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json?channel=' + this.channel.toLowerCase(),
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: 'jsonp',
            success: $.proxy(function (stream) {
                this.live = true;
                this.count = stream[0].channel_count;
                console.log(this); //HERE
            }, this)
        });
```

You run the risk of getting inconsistent results if you don't take the asynchronus response into account when dealing with the data it returns.

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the best answer. I was thinking about that too, but I considered adding async: false, which, according to jQuery API documentation, doesn't work JSONP. Now I don't know how to do this using AJAX, because after adding live and count values (I wanted to add live = false and count = 0 for these objects which don't succeed in AJAX call) I wanted to sort these objects by count descending. Here's the full code: http://jsfiddle.net/almirsarajcic/C4Jur/1/

Comment: I don't quite follow what you're trying to achieve, but it sounds like you should ask it on another question, just to keep it organized...

Comment: Like Slaks said and you told me, I couldn't do that, so I've added what I wanted to do in method called after complete event. I think I'll have to do this in PHP, because I'm not satisfied with this (I need to sort these livestreams by viewers count, but can't because I use two livestream providers).
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

"this" is contextual, you're dropping into closures which change the "this" to something you're not expecting. Consider cacheing the object at the top of the each... Like

```
var $this = $(this);
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with closures.